# Continuous Integration tool with guest restart support

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, buildbot

I would like to build a testing framework for one project. I'm searching for something to build upon, as I don't desire to build everything from scratch.

The architecture I'd wish to create is:

1. A host machine, with VirtualBox host (or different VM software),
2. Collection of guest VMs with different versions of different Operating Systems.

By running a test, the testing framework would run my test on all guest VMs, and present the Pass/Fail verdict for each guest VM.

The most important thing is that the project works mostly between system restarts, so the testing scenarios would mostly look like this:

```
boot guest VM -> (act) -> restart guest VM -> (check) -> verdict
```

I have limited experience with `buildbot`, I've also know the existence of `jenkins`, `bamboo`, `cruisecontrol`, etc, projects, but I don't know if any of these support the 'restarting' of the guest VM during test phase?

Could anyone could please guide me to some CI software that does support my case?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [vSphere plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/vSphere+Cloud+Plugin) which could be a way to go. This allows for the restarting of VMs as a separate step in Jenkins

> vSphere Cloud Plugin
>
> This plugin adds a way to control Virtual
>   Machines hosted in a VMware vSphere server using Jenkins.  You can
>   configure a Jenkins Slave to use a virtual machine, including an
>   optional snapshot name.  If configured to do so, Jenkins will
>   (optionally) revert, then start the virtual machine as a slave.  If
>   configured to do so, Jenkins will also shutdown and (optionally)
>   revert the virtual machine when all jobs have finished processing.
>
> Additionally, you can manipulate your vSphere VMs & templates using
>   any of the vSphere Build steps provided by this plugin.